# Is it possible to select the absolute last grand child of an element using only CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c"></div>
    <div class="c"></div>
    <div class="c"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c"></div>
    <div class="c"></div> <!-- element to select -->
  </div>
  <div class="b">

  </div>
</div>
```

Using `.a .b:last-child .c:last-child` won't work in this case because of the last `div.b` which is empty.

Comment: you should really be doing some research before you ask this sort of question.  Did you have difficulty finding an answer or reading the selector documentation?

Comment: not sure to understand all these *possible duplicate*. How they are related? and no, you cannot do this using CSS, you need JS/jQuery --> `$('.c:last')` will do it

Comment: This is not a duplicate.

Comment: @antoni there are essentially infinite questions that could be asked about how to target specific elements and they will all boil down to the same answer; the flexibility they are after is not possible within the current CSS spec.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to have a selector that looks into the next sibling (to see if empty) and use it in a previous element of the DOM.

The `:empty` pseudo-class can help you to know if an element is empty but it won't help in your case.

`:empty` is supported in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera 9.5+, Internet Explorer 9+, and on Android and iOS.

Also note that an element containing a space is not considered as empty.

Another not well known yet very useful selector is `~`: which means any sibling that come after a specific DOM element. like a `+` except that `~` also target a `.b + .b` if there is another dom element in between that is not a `.b` like a `br` for instance.

I created a Codepen to explore convenient selectors, even if the response is "no you can't do it": https://codepen.io/antoniandre/pen/jOOmKmq

Comment: well.. I'm not sure you should be saying no with any certainty here.. there are logical and relational pseduo class selectors in working draft.  `.a .b:nth-last-child(has( > .c)) .c:last-child` should work in that respect.. or some variation of it  https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational

Comment: This is still no, you can't look ahead and use it in previous element selector, at least not for now :)